# Custom Views Scaffolding in Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding, rails-engines

I'm trying to get custom scaffolding working from my engine.

I followed some tutorial on customizing Rails 3.2 scaffolding in a normal Rails App and put my customized templates in the engines **/lib/templates/erb/scaffold** directory but they don't get picked up by the app that includes the engine. Any suggestions?

Update:
I also tried to override the Rails ScaffoldGenerator's `source_path` and tried some other paths to put my template in, like:
**lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates**

Answer (score 4):

zarazan's answer got me most of the way there, but there are a couple of things wrong with it. Here's what worked for me:

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine

  config.generators do |g|
    g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../../templates', __FILE__)
  end

end
```

Note that this goes in the `generators` section, *not* `app_generators`, and that the path is slightly different.

Also, I think the correct path to store your templates is `lib/templates/erb/scaffold`, optionally replacing erb with whatever language you are using (like haml or slim.) I know this works for slim. The file names are `{_form,edit,index,new,show}.html.erb`.

Answer (score 3):

In the file that you declare your engine use this command:

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine

  config.app_generators do |g|
    g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  end

end
```

It should shift the preference of what template folder Rails uses by default.

Now just put the template files in lib/templates/erb/scaffold/template_name.erb

Where template_name is one of the following: _form.html.erb, edit.html.erb, index.html.erb, new.html.erb, show.html.erb

Once you include the gem you should be able to use the rails generate scaffold command as normal.

Here is an example of an engine that overrides the default scaffolding in rails:

https://github.com/brocktoncg/gemboree

This is where the template directory is located:

https://github.com/brocktoncg/gemboree/tree/master/lib/templates/erb/scaffold

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a controller template? Than you are using the wrong directory. Save your template at 
`lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`

Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/templates.html for an example.

Comment: No I'm searching for a solution for view scaffolding. I updated my question to reflect this better.