# Overriding default scaffold views in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am wanting to override the default scaffold views for my rails 4 app.  I have copied all of the erb scaffold files from railties and placed them in the following folder under my app /lib/templates/erb/scaffold.

I modified the new.erb.html file so that I could tell if the lib/templates erb file is being used to generate the view instead of the default railties file.

After running the command:

```
rails g scaffold Customer code:string name:string
```

and reloading the new customer page it doesn't pick up my customised scaffold file to generate the new customer view.

Is there something else I need to set within the app to tell it to look at the lib/templates folder for scaffold template files?

- Rails version is: Rails 4.1.4
- OS version is: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Ruby version is: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

Cheers,
Leigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution" however I'm not entirely sure why re-running the scaffold command didn't produce the same results. Instead I ran: rails destroy scaffold Customer and then re-ran: rails g scaffold Customer code:string name:string and it worked. The big question will be if I make additional view template changes will I need to do the same again or will re-running the scaffold command work. Time will tell...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem save for the fact that my changes were never showing up no matter how many times I *destroy*ed or *generate*d my scaffold entity.  To fix it, I added the following *defaults* to my `config/application.rb` file (see [Customizing Your Workflow](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.8/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow) at Ruby on Rails Guides):

```
...
class Application < Rails::Application
...
  config.generators do |g|
    g.orm             :active_record
    g.template_engine :erb
    g.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: true
  end
end
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll link to you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420820/custom-views-scaffolding-in-rails-engines]) post which has the answer.
But in short what they say is:
You need to add this code in a file which declares your engine.

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine

  config.app_generators do |g|
    g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  end

end
```

It also links to examples which do what you seem to be looking to do. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks @Vasseurth.  Do you know where the class Engine < Rails::Engine block above needs to be placed?  Do I need to create a new file and place it somewhere in my app or do I edit an existing file?

Comment: Hmm, upon some more investigation it seems that simply placing the templates in lib/templates/erb/scaffold should have done the trick. But looking at the gemboree example, they have that in the lib folder

Comment: I found a "solution" however I'm not entirely sure why re-running the scaffold command didn't produce the same results.  Instead I ran: rails destroy scaffold Customer and then re-ran: rails g scaffold Customer code:string name:string and it worked.  The big question will be if I make additional view template changes will I need to do the same again or will re-running the scaffold command work.  Time will tell...